# How to solve a prime number-logic problem

Tags: puzzle

I am sitting with two other people who are wearing hats with the prime numbers 5 and 11. My hat has a prime number also, but I don't know what it is, nor do each of them know their numbers. It is also known that our three numbers represent side lengths forming a triangle having a perimeter length which is also a prime number. They are each asked if they know their number, and each says no. I answer no also. They are asked again, and say no, and now it is my turn. What is my number?

Note: I have figured out that the only possible numbers I can have are 7 and 13, but I can't seem to narrow it down to which is my number.

Comment: The trick in these problems is to think it through carefully from the others' points of view.  Say you have a $7$.  Then the $5-$person sees $(11,7)$.  How do they reason?  And so on.

Comment: Thanks, lulu, I will try doing that. I can see where if  "5" does see (11,7) on the first round, then she will have to say "yes, I know my number" because her hat would have to be 5 since 5+11+7 =23, satisfying the requirement the triangle's perimeter length is a prime number. If "5" sees (11,13), once again "yes," because her number has to be 5 (7 doesn't work). I don't know, I seem to be going in circles.

Comment: Anyway, I ended up with 7, but not totally certain. Could be 13.